# wkhtmltopdf command fails

Tags: pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, xvfb

I am trying to convert a HTML file to PDF using `wkhtmltopdf`.

For that purpose I have installed wkhtmltopdf on a Debian box and am trying to run this command:

```
/usr/bin/xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" wkhtmltopdf /path/convert.1303714349.4961.html.tmp /path/convert.1303714349.4961.pdf.tmp
```

I get the following error:

```
Loading page (1/2)
Error: Failed loading page file:///path/convert.1303714349.4961.html.tmp (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --ignore-load-errors)
```

The file does exist in `/path/convert.1303714349.4961.html.tmp`, and the permissions are set correctly. Can it have anything to do with the path being prepended with `file://`?

Comment: I had this problem because of a javascript code which reloaded my page while it was converted to pdf. I dunno, maybe this will help somebody :-?

Answer (score 40):

I believe `wkhtmtopdf` does not handle local files with non-typical extensions. Try renaming the input file to `*.html`.

See issue and comments at https://web.archive.org/web/20131124022426/http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=486.

Answer (score 3):

Another useful tip is to replace the spaces in the filename by some char like "_", because of when the filename has spaces the process fails loading page

Answer (score 1):

### Your trouble is caused by the negotiation of user permission between the filesystem, `xvfb-run` `wkhtmltopdf` and headless X11 server.

The User runs this command:

```
cd /home/user;
touch somehtml.html;
/usr/bin/xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" 
     wkhtmltopdf somehtml.html preview.pdf;
```

wkhtmltopdf produces a Warning:

> Warning: Failed loading page
>     file:///home/user/somehtml.html (ignored)

The target PDF file doesn't exist, has missing content from somefile.html or is blank.

### How to reproduce the problem, an sscce:

**Conditions:**

```
64 bit Fedora Linux 17, PC Desktop
Install via a 'sudo yum install wkhtmltopdf'
wkhtmltopdf has version 0.10.0
From a terminal, using xvfb-run
```

**The offending HTML in somehtml.html:**

```
<html>
<head>head tag</head>
  <body>
    <h1>this should be H1<h1>
    Words words words in a paragraph.
  </body>
</html>
```

**Be in a user's directory and run**

```
cd /home/user;
/usr/bin/xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" wkhtmltopdf /home/user/somehtml.html /home/user/preview.pdf
```

**wkhtmltopdf produces a warning**

> Warning: Failed loading page
>     file:///home/user/somehtml.html (ignored)

/home/user/preview.pdf is missing or blank.

### What is causing the problem:

Your `xvfb-run` jails `wkhtmlpdf` to the user and doesn't have permission to read and or write to `/home/user/somehtml.pdf` or `/home/user/preview.pdf`

To see if this is your problem, ask `xvfb-run` what kind of permissions we have?

```
/usr/bin/xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" whoami > /tmp/secret.txt; cat /tmp/secret.txt
```

### Workaround:

`/tmp` typically has looser permissions than /home/user/, so do all your work inside /tmp

```
cd /tmp;
touch /tmp/somehtml.html;
#put above html in somehtml.html
cat /tmp/somehtml.html
    <html>
    <head>head tag</head>
      <body>
        <h1>this should be H1<h1>
        Words words words in a paragraph.
      </body>
    </html>
/usr/bin/xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" wkhtmltopdf /tmp/somehtml.html /tmp/preview.pdf
```

And you should get this stdout:

```
loaded the Generic plugin 
Loading page (1/2)
Printing pages (2/2)
Done
```

And preview.pdf

[image: chrome_wkhtmltopdf_and_xvfb-run]

### Why is not wkhtmltopdf smarter and handling this problem for me?

This is harder than it looks, because wkhtmltopdf has to contend with hostile 3rd party proprietary PDF rendering software (made by adobe?) and they work in concert with browser developers to obfuscate and make access to their engines hard because many large corporations by them money for their top secret source code.  wkhtmltopdf is pricking into that world so that open source people can have it without paying suits in tall office buildings cash money. That's why adobe pay money to developers of browsers to make this hard for us.  We are diluting their profit mechanism, so they retaliate by throwing stop sticks at us where they can.  This is that.  The more we spreads this round the world to novices, the harder the 3rd party throws stop sticks, since you are preventing profit in others.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had any problem with "file://" paths on my Windows 7 box.

Did you try the advice in the error message, `--igonore-load-errors`?

Comment: Where do I set --load-error-handling ignore? In the Rails config initializer?